# E-mail responsivo

Tags: css, email, layout-responsivo, newsletter

Compramos um template de e-mail responsivo, ele ficou 100% responsivo, porém nos apps de e-mail como o do gmail o footer some, a surge um click de "ver toda a mensagem" quebrando a rolagem e abre na versão desktop que não fica resposivo enquanto isso no header já possui o ver na web normal, isso é algo no css?? como posso resolver isso ps. a plataforma de disparo é AllIn[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é pq o Gmail só aceita até uma determinada quantidade de código (texto), até que aparece essa link de "Ver toda a mensagem" Por exemplo ele só aceita 5000mil caracteres e depois gera automaticamente esse link para ver toda a mensagem. A solução e vc diminui a quantidade de código do e-mail retirando código desnecessários ou parte do conteúdo...

Eu não achei uma fonte oficial do Google, mas no Mail Chimp tem a dica https://mailchimp.com/pt/help/gmail-is-clipping-my-email/

> Quando o Gmail corta a mensagem, ele também corta o código de rastreamento que conta as aberturas. P**ara garantir que todas as aberturas sejam rastreadas e o conteúdo completo da sua campanha não seja ocultado em um link**, é importante que a sua mensagem **fique menor do que 102 KB**.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!
Nosso código contem 1861 linhas já com o css, vou verificar o que pode ser extraído dele.

Comment: @CriaçãoPaquetá valeu a força! Verifique isso, alguns geradores de email marketing costumam colocar bastante código desnecessário e o Gmail pode estar ocultando parte do seu conteúdo por isso...